# Is there a way to send a video signal into an Android device?

Tags: video, hdmi, video-recording, video-streaming

I have Samsung 6 and I'd like to use it with Gear VR. I would like to send an external signal into it like my VCR or Laser Disc player (I'm joking I'm not that old, geewhiz). I'm actually thinking of sending a regular HDMI signal into it.

Is there anyway to do this? Even if it requires hacking? I remember at one point it was impossible to send the video signal out an Android device but now it's not so there is hope?

Answer (score 1):

TrinusVR is an app that allows you to stream HD video from you PC to your smartphone, either wireless with some latency, or with a USB cord without latency. Meant for video games but it will stream whatever is on your computer screen. Then you need an HDMI capture device connected to your PC, and you've got a way to port HDMI into your Android. The catch is that it split screens the image for use in VR goggles, but I believe you can bypass that.